# What happens when you allocate on the heap, memory that is referenced in a static variable?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, static, fork, valgrind

For a project written in C where global variables are not authorized, I used a singleton that returns a structure. Then I allocated some memory on a pointer that belongs to my structure. I am wondering about a few things. How does the memory is layed out when this is done ? Is there a better way of doing this ?
My singleton.

```
static t_struct *r(void)
{
 static t_struct s;
 return (&s);
}
```

I allocate some memory.

```
void memory_allocation(int x)
{
 r()->a_ptr_to_another_struct = malloc(sizeof(t_another_struct) * (x));
 ...
}
```

Also it gets a bit complicated as I am forking the process a number of times. Each forks exit(). Should I free the static in each of my fork even though I am exiting ? I am getting some problems for not freeing things when exiting, if anyone has a good book or documentation so I can hold my ground I would be very grateful. I know that the kernel will reclaim memory on exit, but valgrind is not of this opinion.
Would love any recommendation to study this design pattern more carefully as well as potential dangers.

Comment: "How does the memory is layed out when this is done ?" --> the layout really should not  matter.  Lifetime, scope does.

Comment: I just want to understand how static and heap memory are handled when a static variable is allocated some heap memory, as I can't visualize the process correctly. I would love to hear what you mean by lifetime, as well as scope, and how does this affect my program though, because I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Although "static" and "heap" memory are a common memory model.  C does not require that.  I hope you get a good answer with using the more abstract  C model involving "lifetime" and "scope".  Good luck.

Comment: I can't imagine that an even slightly competent reviewer who's supposed to be catching global variables would let a function like `r` through. And does the ban in question mean that you can't see why functions failed when they put that information in `errno`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want valgrind to run clean, you'll need to free the memory in each process.

You can use an `atexit` handler, which gets called after a call to `exit`, to free the memory.

```
void clean_r(void)
{
    free(r()->a_ptr_to_another_struct);
}
```

And set it up at the start of your program:

```
atexit(clean_r);
```

Comment: the struct in `r` is static so every fork is writing to the same struct. There is only one instance and it is not reentrant, The memory allocated is lost

Comment: @0___________ False.  After a `fork`, the entire memory of the process is duplicated in the child process.  Writing memory in one process won't affect any other unless you set up a shared memory segment.

Comment: is there a way to implement my own atexit function ?

Comment: @KarimDhrif `atexit` is a standard function, so you can pass it a function like the one above.